# Using Jquery eq() to get specific DIV?

Tags: jquery

I have a block of code below that I am using when the next button on my quiz is clicked to go to the next question. There are 4 possible answers(input radio buttons) inside each .questionContainer div, of which there are 5 for the 5 questions.

I want to allow the user to click on a specific question number and go right to that question. The .next() line of code is working correctly to advance to the next question and possible answeres, but the line that I have commented out does not work. What am I doing wrong??? Thanks

```
$('.btnNext').click(function(){
    $(this).parents('.questionContainer').fadeOut(500, function(){
        $(this).next().fadeIn(500);
    //$(this).eq(1).fadeIn(500);
    });

});
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest using:

```
$('.questionContainer').eq($(this).index()).fadeIn(500);
```

This assumes that you're clicking an `a` (or other element) which has siblings corresponding to the `.questionContainer` elements that each is supposed to show, resembling:

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div class="questionContainer">
        <!-- question one -->
    </div>
    <div class="questionContainer">
        <!-- question two -->
    </div>
    <div class="questionContainer">
        <!-- question three -->
    </div>
    <div class="questionContainer">
        <!-- question four -->
    </div>
    <div class="questionContainer">
        <!-- question five -->
    </div>
</div>

<div id="buttons">
    <a href="#">Question 1</a>
    <a href="#">Question 2</a>
    <a href="#">Question 3</a>
    <a href="#">Question 4</a>
    <a href="#">Question 5</a>
</div>
```

If the elements you're clicking are not siblings, you can pass a selector to the `index()` method to find the correct index. This can be any CSS-type selector, based on class-name, element-type, parents...etc.

The reason your first piece of code didn't, and *couldn't*, work is that `$(this)` (and `this`), can only refer to a single element/DOM node at a time, therefore `this` (and `$(this)`) always has an implicit index of `0` (being the first, and only, element in a set of one).

References:

- [`index()`](http://api.jquery.com/index/).

Answer (score 0):

You may also want to try using the wildcard "$" which tells jQuery to match any id ending with $; and setting the question's div ids = "q1" through "q5":

```
  var q_nbr = 1 //create a variable in the global scope for the question number
  $(function() {
    $("#btnNext").click(
      function() {
        $("[id$=" + q_nbr + "]").fadeOut(500); // you may wish to omit this
        q_nbr++
        $("[id$=" + q_nbr + "]").fadeIn(500);
      }
    );
  });
```